# Which html tag to use for subtitles? (p, div, or span)

Tags: html

Consider the following hero section:

```html
<div>
  <h1>Welcome to Our Site</h1>
  <subtitle>The place of your dreams.<subtitle>
  <a href="/next-page">Get Started</a>
</div>
```

Now obviously, `<subtitle>` is not a tag. Typically you'd either put a `p` or a `div`, or a block level `span` (modified with css of course).

However, I actually have no idea which one is the correct practice for writing a subtitle.

- It's not `h2` because it's not a heading, it's a subheading.
- It's techincally not a paragraph, so for me the `p` tag doesn't fully make sense.
- `div`s I thought were for separating content on a website, but it's really the only one that makes sense to me to use because it has so many uses.
- If `span`s were block level tag I'd probably use it, but only because I typically associate it with text.

I typically use `div`s, but it still seems strange to me.

Let's say that there was a standard for this, and it could only be one tag...

**Which tag should I be using for subtitles?** Which one makes the most sense semantically and overall?

Comment: Hello, if you often have "subtitles" you can use an h. Classical styling for h are from h1 to h6... If you consider, and use your title with h1, you could use h3, you keep the h2 for "in case of need something in-between". All css libraries, framework have coherent class definition for h1 to h6 but you still can override what you want or write you own.

Comment: don't nest a button inside a link, this doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

That basically depends on the particular context of your (sub-)titles. Since HTML provides a certain hierarchy and structure of elements, which becomes even more important when using e.g. screenreaders which depend on this structure, you might ask yourself to which parent the subtitle would belong the most or whether it should be seen as "independent".

Thus, considering it being an addition to the `h1` element, I would wrap it into a `small` tag within `h1` as follows to maintain the immediate relationship of both, while providing options to (semantically and visually) mark it as a child element. The visual appearance (font size, linebreaks) can be added with CSS. HTML itself should only be about structure.

```html
<h1>
  Main title
  <small>Subtitle</small>
</h1>
```

Using an `h2` element would also be fine, however I would consider that being read more like a "subchapter" with own content. Here, it is common to have multiple `h2`s as childs of `h1`, while the first approach using `small` would only make sense with a single child element.